# how does variational autoencoder reconstruct image?

Tags: machine-learning, autoencoders

I don't understand how encode/decode of VAE works. The encoder p(z|x) is pursued by p(z). So, code z is a random number being independent from x. In other words, x is encoded by a random number z having no mutual information with itself. Why is the reconstruction plausible anyway with VAE?